# Zoomable, printable, scrollable train movement graphs in c#

Tags: c#, plot, charts, vector-graphics, graphing

I need to build a graphic train schedule visualisation tool in C#. Actually I have to rebuild [this perfect tool](http://mbostock.github.io/protovis/ex/caltrain.html) in C#.
[Marey's Trains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJ1hH.png)
The graphs have to be zoomable, scrollable and printable/exportable to PDF with vector graphical elements.

Could you give me some tips? How should I start it? What sort of libraries should I use?

Is it worth to try using graphing libraries like OxyPlot? Maybe it's not the best because of the special axes and irregular grids - as I think. What's your opinion?

[image: example]

Comment: MSChart can export only some EMF vector formats (and png)  and one would have to use custom labels and owner-drawn grids for the vertical grids. Other than that it could do the job, I think..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter which chart tool you use, once you need special types of display you will always have to add some extra coding.

Here is an example of using the `MSChart` control.

Do note that it has a limitation wrt to exporting vector formats:

It can export to various [formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartimageformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), including 3 [`EMF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) types; however only some application can actually use those. Not sure about the PDF libary you use..!

If you can't use the `Emf` formats you can get nice results by making the `Chart` control really big, exporting to `Png` and then making the `Dpi` resolution much larger the the default screen resolution it has after saving.. Setting it to `600` or `1200dpi` should do for most pdf uses..

Now lets look at an example:

[image]

A few notes:

- I have made my life easier in a number of ways. I have only coded for one direction and I have not reversed the rooster, so it goes only bottom to top.
- I have not used real data but made them up.
- I have not created one or more classes to hold the station data; instead I use a very simple `Tuple`.
- I have not created a `DataTable` to hold the train data. Instead I make them up and add them to the chart on the fly..
- I didn't test, but zooming and scrolling should work as well..

Here is the `List<Tuple>` that holds my station data:

```
// station name, distance, type: 0=terminal, 1=normal, 2=main station
List<Tuple<string, double, int>> TrainStops = null;
```

Here is how I set up the chart:

```
Setup24HoursAxis(chart1, DateTime.Today);
TrainStops = SetupTrainStops(17);
SetupTrainStopAxis(chart1);

for (int i = 0; i < 23 * 3; i++)
{
    AddTrainStopSeries(chart1, DateTime.Today.Date.AddMinutes(i * 20),
                       17 - rnd.Next(4), i% 5 == 0 ? 1 : 0);
}
// this exports the image above:
chart1.SaveImage("D:\\trains.png", ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

This creates one train every 20 minutes with 14-17 stops and every 5th train a fast one.

Here are the routines I call:

Setting up the x-axis for hold one day's worth of data is straightforward.

```
public static void Setup24HoursAxis(Chart chart, DateTime dt)
{
    chart.Legends[0].Enabled = false;

    Axis ax = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
    ax.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;
    ax.Interval = 1;
    ax.Minimum =  dt.ToOADate();
    ax.Maximum = (dt.AddHours(24)).ToOADate();
    ax.LabelStyle.Format = "H:mm";
}
```

Creating a List of stations with random distances is also very simple. I made the 1st and last ones terminals and every 5th a main station.

```
public List<Tuple<string, double, int>> SetupTrainStops(int count)
{
    var stops = new List<Tuple<string, double, int>>();
    Random rnd = new Random(count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        string n = (char)(i+(byte)'A') + "-Street";
        double d = 1 + rnd.Next(3) + rnd.Next(4) + rnd.Next(5) / 10d;
        if (d < 3) d = 3;  // a minimum distance so the label won't touch
        int t = (i == 0 | i == count-1) ? 0 : rnd.Next(5)==0 ? 2 : 1;
        var ts = new Tuple<string, double, int>(n, d, t);
        stops.Add(ts);
    }
    return stops;
}
```

Now that we have the train stops we can set up the y-axis:

```
public void SetupTrainStopAxis(Chart chart)
{
    Axis ay = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
    ay.LabelStyle.Font = new Font("Consolas", 8f);
    double totalDist = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < TrainStops.Count; i++)
    {
        CustomLabel cl = new CustomLabel();
        cl.Text = TrainStops[i].Item1;
        cl.FromPosition = totalDist - 0.1d;
        cl.ToPosition = totalDist + 0.1d;
        totalDist += TrainStops[i].Item2;
        cl.ForeColor = TrainStops[i].Item3 == 1 ? Color.DimGray : Color.Black;
        ay.CustomLabels.Add(cl);
    }
    ay.Minimum = 0;
    ay.Maximum = totalDist;
    ay.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
    ay.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
}
```

A few notes are called for here:

- As the values are quite dynamic we can't use normal `Labels` which would come with the fixed `Interval` spacing.
- So we create `CustomLabels` instead.
- For these we need two values to determine the space into which they shall be centered. So we create a small span by adding/subtracting `0.1d`.
- We have calculated the total distance and use it to set up the `Maximum` of the y-axis. Again: To mimick the schedule you show you will have to do some reversing here and there..
- By adding `CustomLabels` the normal ones are turned off automatically. As we need `MajorGridlines` at the **irregular** intervals we also turn the normal ones off. Hence we must draw them ourselves. Not really hard as you can see..:

For this we code one of the `xxxPaint` events:

```
private void chart1_PostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    Axis ay = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
    Axis ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;

    int x0 = (int) ax.ValueToPixelPosition(ax.Minimum);
    int x1 = (int) ax.ValueToPixelPosition(ax.Maximum);

    double totalDist = 0;
    foreach (var ts in TrainStops)
    {
        int y = (int)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(totalDist);
        totalDist += ts.Item2;
        using (Pen p = new Pen(ts.Item3 == 1 ? Color.DarkGray : Color.Black, 
                               ts.Item3 == 1 ? 0.5f : 1f))
            e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawLine(p, x0 + 1, y, x1, y);
    }
    // ** Insert marker drawing code (from update below) here !
}
```

Note the use of the `ValueToPixelPosition` conversion functions of the axes!

Now for the last part: How to add a `Series` of train data..:

```
public void AddTrainStopSeries(Chart chart, DateTime start, int count, int speed)
{
    Series s = chart.Series.Add(start.ToShortTimeString());
    s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    s.Color = speed == 0 ? Color.Black : Color.Brown;
    s.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
    s.MarkerSize = 4;

    double totalDist = 0;
    DateTime ct = start;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var ts = TrainStops[i];
        ct = ct.AddMinutes(ts.Item2 * (speed == 0 ? 1 : 1.1d));
        DataPoint dp = new DataPoint( ct.ToOADate(), totalDist );
        totalDist += TrainStops[i].Item2;
        s.Points.Add(dp);
    }
}
```

Note that since my data don't contain real arrival/departure times I calculated them from the distance and some speed factor. You, of course, would use your data!

Also note that I have used a `Line` chart with extra `Marker` circles.

Also note that each train series can easily be disabled/hidden or brought back again.

Let's show only the fast trains:

```
private void cbx_ShowOnlyFastTrains_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Series s in chart1.Series)
        s.Enabled = !cbx_ShowOnlyFastTrains.Checked || s.Color == Color.Brown;
}
```

Of course for a robust application you will not rely ona magic color ;-)
Instead you could add a `Tag` object to the `Series` to hold all sorts of train info.

**Update**: As you noticed the drawn `GridLines` cover the `Markers`. You can insert this piece of code here (**); it will owner-draw the `Markers` at the end of the `xxxPaint` event.

```
int w = chart1.Series[0].MarkerSize;
foreach(Series s in chart1.Series)
foreach(DataPoint dp in s.Points)
{
    int x = (int) ax.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.XValue) - w / 2;
    int y = (int) ay.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.YValues[0])- w / 2;
        using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(dp.Color))
            e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.FillEllipse(b, x, y, w, w);
}
```

Close-up:

[image]

Comment: Wow, dear TaW, **thanks a lot** for this detailed solution and explanation! It's much more than I hoped. You made solutions for my most important problem: the irregular Y axis and grid, it works propeply! ;)
Meanwhile I found an attempt for this case in the [example library of OxyPlot](https://github.com/ylatuya/oxyplot/blob/master/Source/Examples/ExampleLibrary/Examples/MiscExamples.cs) (PlotModel TrainSchedule) , but it also contains only a regular Y axis without the station names.
MSChart seems to be enough and it's well documented. Cool! Thanks again, I'll post the result later.

Comment: in this way, the post-drawn gridlines come in front of the markers ([screenshot here](http://i.imgur.com/BqSojPb.png)) even if they're drawn at PrePaint or at PostPaint. Is there a way to send them behind the markers? Should I move them to BackImage or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Ah, interesting! The Backimage is not really a good idea, after all the chart needs to be dynamic. I have  added code for drawing the markers..

Comment: Thanks for the update! :) Well, the problem also appears in case of a train passes over a station ([screenshot here, example at D-Street](http://i.imgur.com/FdC8mh3.png)): in this case the line is covered by the gridline. So should I redraw (with extending your code for the markers) all the pieces of the chart near the gridlines?

Comment: Hm, not sure which part you mean. The parts that cross a little over the y-axis? The 2nd screenshot is not how it looks here. Did you add the code at the right positon, ie after drawing the gridlines??

Comment: For [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/wBiSoTL.png), I added your update - OK, it redraws the markers. But yes, I mean the tiny line-gridline crosses that i highlighted.

Comment: Well, I would simply add 1 or 2 to the x coordinate.. Adding another chartarea is a possibilty for some things but also a really big cannon ;-) - I just tried it and here 1 pixel is enough: `e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawLine(p, x0, y, x1+1, y);`